# How to create multiple Mouse controls which work separately in C#?

Tags: c#, mouse, mouseevent, multipoint

I am implementing a program in C# which can "Play" multiple instance of a game at the same time. The actions of the spawned instance is based on my actions. For example, when i click at position X, Y of the main instance, there will be mouse click at the same position in all other spawned instance.

I can do the mouse click, mouse down, mouse up by hooking the mouse event, and simulate the same mouse click on position based on the position of the each game window. However, this approach does not help if it comes to mouse dragging. And it has some setback in performance when i have to loop all my game instances to do a virtual mouse click.

I have found out that it is possible to create multiple mouse using the MultiPoint SDK from Microsoft. However, I could not find any documentation about if it is possible to simulate the multiple mouse click events (other than mine) in C#? If it is then how can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are manipulating a program you didn't write, I think you might be using the wrong API for the job.

If you need to script multiple actions on multiple windows, you are probably better off running them sequentially.  It will be easier to code and debug and you won't have to do anything special.  Just script each action sequentially and then execute them.

Comment: You mean using Marco? But it does not support some real time modification. Since this application is like an Emulator to "actually" run a game on it, what i need is to be able to do some "real" gameplay test. Anyway, this approach seems to be pointless. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What I meant is instead of trying to use the multipoint API, is to simply script the clicks one by one on multiple app windows.  If you need real time actions and you can't modify the code then I recommend that you spin out some VMs and script your tests across the farm.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to make an Emulator based on the .dll instead. I will mark your post as an answer and close this question.